# What's a good way to handle Generic Foreign Keys in JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, generics, jpa, foreign-keys

We have an Spring 3.2, Hibernate 4.2 application.

Our application has an upload module, where you can basically upload all kinds of files. A file upload generates also a database entry:

```
id, directory, filename, mimeType, userId
```

So basically it should be possible to upload a file from everywhere in the application. And we don't want a new UploadEntity for every possible Entity. So we thought about using some kind of generic table for uploads:

```
id, directory, filename, mimeType, userId, FOREIGN_KEY
```

The problem of course is, that we can't set a concrete data type for this foreign key in JPA, because it can point to Entity A or B or C or ... We use `UUID` as keys in our application, so we thought about two solutions:

1. Make the `foreignKey` simply of type `UUID` and always save the foreign entity's id.
2. Make the `foreignKey` of type `Object` with a `@ManyToOne` annotation, but of course we can't provide a target entity for that.

But maybe there's some other much better/easier solution for this. What do you think?

---

I forgot to tell you, that each entity we use implements `Persistable<UUID>`, so is it possible to use this interface as type for the foreign key?

Btw: We need **never** to use the reference from `UploadedItem -> SomeEntity`. We only need the other way: `SomeEntity -> UploadedItem`.

Comment: You might be interested into the [`Any`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Any.html) hibernate annotation.

Comment: I've never seen this annotation before :) Maybe there's also a way to achieve this with standard JPA annotations?

Comment: You want heterogeneous SomeEntity to reference homogeneous UploadedItem? Why do you need a two way reference, why not just have an optional OneToOne to UploadedItem (or OneToMany) in SomeEntity? If the other way around why not make SomeEntity have a base Entity and have UpdatedItem reference it? Then you can just subclass SomeEntity with A, B, or C?

Comment: Yeah, we considered a subclass, but were not sure if it's really nice. So do we need a real class, or is the `Persistable<UUID>` interface enough?

Comment: @BenjaminM why won't separate one to many relationships defined in A,B,C to uploaded item entity work ?

Comment: @DevBlanked sorry, i don't get what you mean. If you like to, please post an *Answer* to this question with an example :) Thanks!